# Predicate Problem when fetching objects in a To-Many relationship

Tags: core-data, entity-relationship, nspredicate

I have a simple situation where I have two entities related with Many-To-Many relationship.

Two objects, Alarms and Tags.  When I want to fetch all the Alarms associated with a given Tag, I tried this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN tags", theTag];
```

What I get is all Alarms, not just those related to the Tag.

However, trying this the other way around works:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF in %@", theTag.alarms];
```

For complicated reasons having to do with code reuse, I really need the first one to work.  Any help would be much appreciated!    Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Tag` object, then you can get all of its alarms by doing:

```
NSSet *alarms = [theTag alarms];
```

If for some bizarre reason you have to do this with a fetch request (which you shouldn't), your predicate should be:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags CONTAINS %@", theTag];
```

Comment: Of course, of course.  Sometimes, you just need someone to hit you on the side of the head...  Appreciate it!